# PyQt5 - how to disable focus/user interaction for entire window/QWidget

Tags: pyqt5, focus, qwidget

How do you disable focus on an entire QWidget? When I self.show a window (loading window), I want to disable user interaction with the rest of the program.

I've tried self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show the loading window and prevent the user to click/activate any other window until it's closed? Then, use a QDialog and call its [`exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) or [`open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#open) functions, so that you get a [modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).

Comment: Also see: [QSplashScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplashscreen.html).

Comment: try to disable the main widget